# debug java part of the flex application in separate IDE

Tags: java, apache-flex

I am using two separate Eclipse IDE; one for Flex code and one for Java services.

I can run my Flex application by right clicking the application and debug as > flex appication, it works fine;
but at the same instance i want to debug the java side.

Is it possible ?

Comment: How do you normally debug the Java services?

Answer (score 0):

You would use your Java Eclipse IDE and then configure it for *remote debugging* "as usual". If you are running your Java service with Tomcat then you could follow [these instructions](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing#Q2):

> - Make sure that Tomcat is started in remote debugging mode ... and that your app is deployed.
> - Make sure that you have the sources for the code that you are trying to debug in your IDE. For the libraries and for Tomcat itself you can "attach" the sources to the jar files: open a class file and then click *"Attach Source..."* button.
> - If you have a servlet or something, set a breakpoint where it is sure to hit on the next request.
> - Go to *"Run->Debug Configurations..."*. Click on *"Remote Java Applications"*, then click *"New"*. Type in the title. Note that port 8000 from the Tomcat instructions. Save and run.
> - Eclipse will connect to the JVM that Tomcat is running under. Wow, that was easy!

Now run your Flex application and execute the part which is calling your specific Java service code. Boom you hit the breakpoint!